How to change the precision of a floating point in C at runtime?
How to make a variable float complex or double complex depending on user input?
I'm trying to plot the Mandelbrot set and I have the same long code for float and double but in some cases float is not precise enough and double is too slow. I'm running it on a low-performance calculator, so float is less than 1 second and double takes at least 5 seconds. I'd like to let the user choose precision over speed or speed over precision. I would like to get something like this:
int user_input;
scanf("%d", &user_input);

switch (user_input) {
      case 0:
          float z;
          float c;
          break;
      case 1:
          double z;
          double c;
          break;
}
for(int i=0;i<1920;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<1080;j++){
        z=0.0+0.0*I;
        c=(i+j*I)/Zoom
}}

Expected outcome: if the user types 0, then all the calculations are performed using floats, and if the user types 1, the calculations are performed using doubles.
But this throws error: conflicting types for ‘z’; have ‘double’, previous declaration of ‘z’ with type ‘float’.
Is something like this possible in C?
I tried making two different varables for float and double but changing them in all the code (I have way more code) would be long and tedious.

Are you sure double presents a performance issue vs float for you?  I could maybe see that if you were moving large numbers of them back and forth between memory and CPU, where it could be a memory bandwidth issue, but computationally, double usually is not slower than float.  In fact, it's not uncommon for double to be faster.

@JohnBollinger Yes, i'm doing it on a calculator so the change is very visible. Less than 1 second for float and at least 5 seconds for double

Some CPU that has hardware float support but double is emulated in software?

The CPU is 32 bits so yes, double is emulated but it's slow

It does not follow that a 32-bit processor has a single precision FPU, so that is non-sequitur.  That is true for Cortex-M4 FPU, but not generally.

That is not the only error, z and c are not even in scope at the point of use.

The only viable solution on modern systems which supports dynamic linking is to compile one version of your program using float and another using double. Then the main program will load the correct version of the dynamic library and it will execute the requested version.

My answer mentions this ("create two libraries, then load the appropriate one at run-time.") The answer you just said didn't answer the OP's question. So which is it? Does this answer the question or not?

This is exactly the answer I wanted!

You can't change the type of a variable after it's been compiled, but you can use a function-like macro to make a different version of the same function for each type you might use without needing to duplicate code, much as you might use templates in other languages:
#include <stdio.h>

#define MANDELBROT(T)               \
void mandelbrot_##T(T I, T Zoom) {  \
    T z, c;                         \
    for(int i=0;i<1920;i++){        \
        for(int j=0;j<1080;j++){    \
            z=0.0+0.0*I;            \
            c=(i+j*I)/Zoom;         \
        }                           \
    }                               \
}

MANDELBROT(double)
MANDELBROT(float)

int main(void) {
    int user_input;
    scanf("%d", &user_input);

    double Zoom = 1.0, I = 1.0;
    if (user_input) {
        mandelbrot_double(I, Zoom);
    }
    else {
        mandelbrot_float(I, Zoom);
    }
}


If you've got a bunch of functions like this, and you don't want to declare absolutely everything as a macro (since putting backslashes after every line is annoying, and it makes it harder for debuggers to tell what lines things are defined on), you can instead do it like this:
templates.h:
/* 
By wrapping all function names in the NAME macro, we get a different identifier
depending on whether we defined T as double or float before #including this file:
NAME("foo") will expand to "foo_double" if T is double.

Sometimes we have to do some minor wizardry to get a macro to fully expand,
which is why we have NAME2 and NAME3. Passing a macro to another 
macro sets a dirty-bit that causes it to be expanded properly.
*/

#define NAME3(S,U) S ## _ ## U
#define NAME2(S,U) NAME3(S,U)
#define NAME(S) NAME2(S,T)

void NAME(mandelbrot)(T I, T Zoom) {
    T z, c;
    for(int i=0;i<1920;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<1080;j++){
            z=0.0+0.0*I;
            c=(i+j*I)/Zoom;
        }
    } 
}

#undef T
#undef NAME
#undef NAME2
#undef NAME3

main.c:
#define T double
#include "templates.h"
#define T float
#include "templates.h"

int main(void) {
    mandelbrot_double(1,1);
    mandelbrot_float(1,1);
}

A side note: as chux pointed out in the comments, I is a macro from complex.h, so you should name that something else (unless that macro is what you were intending to use).

Best combined with C99 type generic math, so that sqrt() etc. in the float version doesn't drag in doubles.

@Shawn it is done compile time too. C generics are not resolved runtime

@0___________ To elaborate, normal sqrt() takes a double and returns a double, necessitating conversions between float and double. Using tgmath routines instead would result in sqrtf() being used instead in a float version of the function being generated, staying on the fast path. This happens at compile time, yes. Did something about my first comment suggest it doesn't?

@chux-ReinstateMonica That identifier came from OP's code. I left the code unchanged except where needed to make the macro work, so as to not mix up two different sets of changes (also, I didn't notice the name collision when I copied it over).  But you're right about the name collision; I'll add a note to that effect.

@chux-ReinstateMonica OP does mention double complex and float complex types. Bet they just forgot to include the complex part in that non-working code fragment.

Sorry - when I read z=0.0+0.0*I; I thought OP was multiplying by the index i.  Suggestion removed.

You can't. The compiler needs to know the type of the variable in order to generate the appropriate code.
In your scenario, I would create a program that could be compiled into two different executables: one that uses float, and one that uses double.
#ifdef USEDOUBLE
   typedef double Number;
#else
   typedef float Number;
#endif

Number z;

gcc             plot.c -o plot_float
gcc -DUSEDOUBLE plot.c -o plot_double

Another possibility is to create two versions of everything. You don't want to actually write two of everything, so you'd use the earlier approach to create two libraries, then load the appropriate one at run-time.

He asked about runtime solution

He will need to do in many places as float functions (from math.h for example) are not the same as double double. Otherwise floats will be converted to doubles and back to floats

This is correct. If speed is an issue you must compile either for double or for float. You cannot magically do both.

@0___________, Re "He asked about runtime solution", Did you not read the answer? I said it's not possible. I also provided two workarounds, the second of which is a "runtime solution".
